# Improved OCR result using pytesseract

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract

I am trying to extract text from image, but it is not able to extract all the text

```
from pytesseract import image_to_string
import re
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = Image.open("test.png")
width, height = img.size
new_size = width*6, height*6
img = img.resize(new_size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
img = img.convert('L')
abc = img.point(lambda x: 0 if x < 170 else 300, '1')
image_to_string(abc)
```

Result:

```
'wide sar da\n\nDemo Bank of India\n\n373, COMMERCIAL POINT BRANCH\nNETAJI SUBHAS ROAD\n\nKOLKATA 700001\nFS Code DOBIK003S9122\n\n@vwvw-'
```

It is not accurately identifying IFSC code.
What should I do to increase accuracy

Comment: This question might be a better fit for [stats.se]